# Converting elements in an array to a full sentence string

Tags: javascript, string

```
function pigIt(str){
  let latin = str.split(' ').map(x => x.slice(0,1) + 'ay')
  let latinTwo = str.split(' ').map(x => x.slice(1, str.length-1))
  for (let i = 0; i < latin.length; i++) {
     let pig = latinTwo[i].concat(latin[i])
     console.log(pig)
  } 
}
```

Testcase:
Test.assertEquals(pigIt('Pig latin is cool'),'igPay atinlay siay oolcay')

My current array of pig contains =
igPay
atinlay
siay
oolcay

I am wondering how I can join this into a full sentence, I've tried using the join method... Any help is much appreciated!

I've tried using the join method however I get an error code.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show how you tried the join call.

Comment: Have you tried `return latinTwo.join(' ');`?

Comment: `string.split("")` counterintuitively splits by UTF-16 code units, which is not something you usually want. [Do _not_ use `.split("")`](/a/38901550/4642212). `slice`, `substring`, and the deprecated `substr` have the same problem. Use `Array.from(string)` to split by characters instead.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach:

```js
function pigIt(s) { 
  return s.split(' ').map(i=>i.substring(1)+i.charAt(0)+'ay').join(' ')
}

console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool'))
```

you can also do:

```js
function pigIt(s) {
  return s.split(' ').map(([a,...b])=>[...b,a,'ay'].join('')).join(' ')
}

console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in right direction, You just have to assign the concatenated string into a variable instead of reassigning it to a whole variable again.

**Note :** `.join` method is helpful for arrays, for strings `.concat` is the method to join.

Live Demo **:**

```js
function pigIt(str) {
  let pig = ''
  let latin = str.split(' ').map(x => x.slice(0,1) + 'ay')
  let latinTwo = str.split(' ').map(x => x.slice(1, str.length-1))
  for (let i = 0; i < latin.length; i++) {
     pig += latinTwo[i].concat(latin[i], " ")
  }
  return pig;
}

console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool').trim());
```